# What is the constructor with which Object is created?

Tags: javascript

There is a global constructor `Object`. It contains some of its own properties, and it also has a `prototype` that contains other properties.

We know that the `_proto_` of an object refers to the `prototype` of the constructor with which it was created.

Ok, `Object` has its own properties and is `Object.prototype`. But when I output `Object._proto_` to the console, I get a constructor function with properties like `bind`, `call`, `arguments` and so on.

Does it mean `Object` is created using this constructor?
Why does it have the properties of a "normal" function?

Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: *Then why aren't these properties in the Function?* Not sure what you mean by this - they are. `Object.__proto__.call === Function.call`, all referencing the `Function.prototype.call`

Comment: @CertainPerformance, thanks, I already saw it and got confused even more.

Comment: Yes, the `Object` constructor is a normal function. `typeof Object === "function"`, like all constructors.

Comment: @Ry-, thanks. 

Can I assume that constructor prototypes inherit from other prototypes (`Array.prototype._proto_ === Object.prototype`), and constructors themselves inherit from a normal function `(Array._proto_ === Function.prototype`)?

Comment: @Denkhis: Yep, that’s right.